# Updating DataFrame column where another column matches the keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to update the following DataFrame with a dictionary:

```
     NHGISST NHGISCTY  ...     id district_assignment
0        220     0510  ...  26588                   5
1        220     0510  ...  26589                   5
2        220     0650  ...  26627                   2
3        220     0650  ...  26628                   2
4        220     0710  ...  26629                   6
...      ...      ...  ...    ...                 ...
1101     220     0050  ...  62152                   4
1102     220     0050  ...  62153                   4
1103     220     0330  ...  62182                   4
1104     220     0330  ...  62183                   0
1105     220     0190  ...  62184                   3
```

```
id_dict = {'26588': 0, '26627': 3, '27648': 4, '27649': 4, '28163': 4, '28164': 4, '28676': 4, '28166': 4, '28167': 4, '28169': 4, '28170': 4, '28172': 4, '27663': 4, '28177': 4, '36377': 4, '36379': 4, '36381': 4, '36382': 4, '28196': 4, '37927': 4, '28211': 4, '27701': 4, '27702': 4, '27704': 4, '27195': 4, '28220': 3...}
```

Specifically, I want to update every row of the DataFrame that matches `id_dict` with the new `district_assignment`. For instance, after the update, the rows with id `26588` and `26627` (among others) would be updated to the new values 0 and 3 respectively.

```
     NHGISST NHGISCTY  ...     id district_assignment
0        220     0510  ...  26588                   0
1        220     0510  ...  26589                   5
2        220     0650  ...  26627                   3
3        220     0650  ...  26628                   2
4        220     0710  ...  26629                   6
...      ...      ...  ...    ...                 ...
```

Here's how I would do it if I was using a non-DataFrame data structure:

```py
for row in df:
  if row['id'] in id_dict:
     row['district_assignment'] = id_dict[row['id']]
```

But I don't know how to do this in the idiomatic vectorised way.

Comment: the built-in [dataframe.reaplce()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method takes a dictionary to map replacements, or [df.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html?highlight=update#pandas.DataFrame.update) would work if you made the update dict into another dataframe

Comment: I can't get the dataframe.replace() method to work, because I need to replace a column's value ('district_assignment') depending on whether another column's value matches ('id')

Comment: `df['district_assignment'] = df['id'].map(id_dict)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Not every id is in id_dict, so what you suggested will give `NaN` values

Comment: You can use `np.where` to check for `NaN` and update.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry, i don't quite get you --- could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `map` with `fillna`:

```
s = df['id'].astype(str).map(id_dict)

df['district_assignment'] = s.fillna(df['district_assignment'])
```

Output:

```
      NHGISST  NHGISCTY  ...     id  district_assignment
0         220       510  ...  26588                  0.0
1         220       510  ...  26589                  5.0
2         220       650  ...  26627                  2.0
3         220       650  ...  26628                  2.0
4         220       710  ...  26629                  6.0
1101      220        50  ...  62152                  4.0
1102      220        50  ...  62153                  4.0
1103      220       330  ...  62182                  4.0
1104      220       330  ...  62183                  0.0
1105      220       190  ...  62184                  3.0
```

Comment: What is the `s` here? Also, if you already mutated `df['district_assignment']` in the previous `df['district_assignment'] = df['id'].map(id_dict)`, will `fillna` still work?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what `s` is. You can certainly chain them.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. That's a trick I'll have to remember. I wonder why it changes the type of `district_assignment` to (what appears to be) a Float? Is there any way to change it back?

Comment: You can always chain `.astype(int)` to that.